# return struct by public function crashes instance pointer

Tags: c++, stm32, rtos, keil

i'm new here in c++ and RTOS, so don't blame me or laugh at me pls

i have:

```
typedef struct
{
//... 10 uint8 and 2 enums
} tStruct1;
typedef struct
{
//... slightly different, but completely different enums
} tStruct2;

class someClass
{
  private:
    struct
    {
      //...
      union
      {
        tStruct1 s1;
        tStruct2 s2;
      } data;
    } node[10];
  //...
  public:
    unsigned int length;

    tStruct1 Get1(void);
    tStruct2 Get2(void);
  //...
}

tStruct1 someClass::Get1(void)
{
  //...
  length--;
  return node[length].data.s1;
}

tStruct2 someClass::Get2(void)
{
  //...
  length--;
  return node[length].data.s2;
}
```

and in someOtherClass:

```
someClass * inst1 = new someClass();
```

this works fine:

```
inst1->Get1(void); //useless...
```

and this:

```
tStruct1 something = inst1->Get1(void);
```

moves inst1 somewhere else. It happens 3 instructions **before** branch to the function, stack pointer decrements by 0x14 (sizeof structure elements is probably 0x12 + alignment -> I think it's ok), and increments back. Function itself seems to work allright. Returned value is some uninitialized value.

```
bool result = instance_of_someOtherClass->inst1->Set(tStruct1);
```

works also fine.

Those 2 calls are done from different threads. Anyway, I'm going to throw this class away because the project changed, but I want to know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: On an unrelated note, you don't need `typedef` for the structures when programming in C++, a `struct` and a `class` are basically the same thing.

Comment: As for your problem, I'm not sure what the problem *is*? Is the assembler code generated suspicious? If so can you please show the assembly code, with comments about what you find suspicious about it?

Comment: There isn't really enough code to say.  For instance, you don't show how you populate `node`.  One possibility would be that calling `Get1()` when `node` is empty (and `length` is `0`) would invoke undefined behavior ( http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213 ), which could include what you're seeing.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg Problem is, that the `inst1` is lost and the function doesn't return desired value

Comment: @Max Lybbert Actually, it's a static queue, I put data in in one thread (that's the `bool Set(tStruct1)` function) and poll it for nonzero length in other, then trying to `Get1()`. Also checking the length inside, this is only simplified. When tracing `Get1()`'s body, there really are the data I have put in, calling the function **and** assigning returned value is the problem.

Comment: Well, then, you'll need more code.  The code you posted doesn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Well, there's a lot of regarding code around with lots of ballast and company know-how, I'm not going to clean it for half a day.

Comment: 1) create inst of `class1` working with serial, run thread
2) create inst of `class2` which has a pointer to instance of `class1`, run thread
3) init `class1` - init serial, create 2 instances of `queue`, 1st for command, 2nd for answer
class1 waits for `cmd_queue` not empty
4) class2 calls `class1->cmd_queue->insert(cmd2)` - OK
5) class1 assigns `cmd1 = cmd_queue->retrieve()` - value inside `retrieve()` is ok, `cmd_queue` points to uninit memory. Pointer is destroyed by first instruction of the assignment line. I'm watching for hints, not debugging my code...

Comment: You said "RTOS" ? Try to increase stack to problematic task. Also, stack monitor (in debug branch of firmware) can be very useful.